# Can I move the beer to another location while its fermenting?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, wort, fermenter

I have my equipment in a town that is 2 hours from where I live, this last month is being hard to travel there too often so it is making very complicate the fermenting and bottling process. So I'm wondering if I can bring home the fermenter and continue the process here.

- Should I bring the wort without adding the Yeasts?
- Should I add the yeasts and then bring the fermenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way should be fine. Although I'd probably pitch the yeast before moving it just to avoid having to have another thing to do after moving it. 2 hours probably isn't enough for it to start fermenting vigorously enough to even pop a plugged bung out so it won't cause problems as long as it's secured in your car.

Just think of it as really good oxygenation of your wort. I have done this before a few times, and never had any issues. Just keep a little spray bottle of sanitizer in case your bung pops out.